# Check if related model have entry in another related model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have following models and there relation

Models

```
User
Product
Orders
OrderProduct
ProductReviews
```

Relations

```
User hasMany Orders
Orders hasMany OrderProdut
User hasMany ProductReview
Product hasMany ProductReview
ProductReview belongsTo User
```

Inside the product page all the reviews for that product is listed with the user details who made the review.
I want to check if review in list has made a purchase of the reviewed product.

So far i have done this with php loops and eager loading. Is there a better way to do this

```
$product = Product::with([
    'reviews'=>function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 1);
    },
    'reviews.user'
])->first();

if($product){
    $product->load(['reviews.user.orders.orderProducts' => function($q) use($product){
        $q->where('product_id',$product->id);
    }]);
}

foreach ($product->reviews as $review){
    $review->purchased_from_microless = false;
    foreach ($review->user->orders as $order) {
        if($order->orderProducts->count()){
            $review->purchased_from_microless = true;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the need for the `->where()` clause in the `$product->load`. The product `reviews` should only be loaded based on relation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to inline the query to check if reviewed product was purchased:

```
$product = Product::with([
    'reviews' => function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 1);
    },
    'reviews.user.orders'
])->first();

$reviews = $product
    ->reviews
    ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        $wasPurchased = $review->user->orders->orderProduct()->where('product_id', $product->id)->count() > 0;

        $review['purchased_from_microless'] = $wasPurchased;

        return $review;
    })->all();
```

Where, the reviews collection is looped through with a check to see if the review's user's orders has an product which has the id of the product in question.

Return `true` if the count is greater than one.